# MVC - Recordset Inside Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am very new to .NET MVC and trying to learn MVC.  I know that I am doing total wrong here, so I need your help. What I try to do is listing a set of 10 companies, then for each of those company listing the contacts based on the companyID.  Please assume that the Entitites and DbContext are set properly, just the problem is between Controller and View is where I couldn't figure out how to:

Here is my Model:

```
namespace ERP.Models

    {
        [Table("ERP_Company")]
        public class ERP_Company
        {
            [Key]
            public int CompanyID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        [Table("ERP_CompanyContact")]
        public class ERP_Contact
        {
            [Key]
            public int ContactID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The methods for getting Company and Contact list from the database:

```
namespace ERP.Models
{
    public class Method1
    {
        private ERPEntities db = new ERPEntities();

        public List<ERP_Company> getCompanyList()
        {
            List<ERP_Company> companyList = (
                from c in db.ERP_Company
                where c.Name.Contains("Network")
                select c).Take(10).ToList();    
            return companyList;
        }

        public List<ERP_Contact> getContactList(int CompanyID)
        {
            List<ERP_Contact> contactList = (
                from cc in db.ERP_CompanyContact
                where cc.CompanyID == CompanyID
                select cc).Take(50).ToList();
            return contactList;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my controller where I am doing wrong:

```
namespace ERP.Controllers
{
    public class Test1Controller : Controller
    {
        //private ERPEntities db = new ERPEntities();

        Method1 _repository = new Method1();     
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Company"] = _repository.getCompanyList();
            ViewData["Contact"] = _repository.getContactList(CompanyID);  // <-- Incorrect Here, but just to show that I want to pass the CompanyID
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, the View which I want to list the Company, then query all contacts based on CompanyID and list them.

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in ViewData["Company"] as List <ERP.Models.ERP_Company> 
    )
    {         
        <li>@item.CompanyID | @item.Name</li>

        <!-- Here is an EXAMPLE that I want to QUERY the Contact recordset and list all the contacts based on the CompanyID -->
        <ul>
            @for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {<li>Contact @i</li>}                            
        </ul> 
    }
</ul>
```

Is it possible to loop through the Contact model (or recordset) within a loop? How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: firstly why aren't you using a ViewModel instead of the ViewData? Secondly if you structure your model correctly you can attach a list of contacts to each company within the code-behind, and then in the view you just loop through them. If you're using entity framework or similar ORM to query your data, it can probably do that for you automagically.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the response. I am new to MVC and I thought using ViewData so I can pass multiple models (Company and Contact).  Would you please provide sample codes?

Comment: ViewBag and ViewData seem nice and simple but they are generally a bad idea.  For something like this, create a ViewModel.  This is a model which has exactly the values you want to use in your view.  For this it would be a company and a List<Contact>.  Then set those values just like you did with the ViewData.

Comment: @nurdyguy please help with sample codes if you don't mind.  I am a beginner of this .NET MVC.  Thanks

Comment: Can someone please help me with sample codes ViewModel for my two ERP_Company and ERP_Contact models above?  I am reading about the ViewModel now and still wrap my head around this concept.

Comment: You need a view model with properties `int CompanyID`, `string Name` and `IEnumerable<ERP_Contact>`

Comment: It's just a class which contains the properties you want. Are you new to C# / .NET as a whole, or just MVC? BTW Microsoft has some good tutorials about MVC which will introduce you to the key concepts including models / viewmodels. If you haven't taken that, I suggest you do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would implement your case, not in a best way but in a simple way.

**Entities:**

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class CompanyService
{
    public List<Company> getCompanyList()
    {
        using (ERPEntities db = new ERPEntities())
        {
            return db.Companies
                     .Include("Contacts")
                     .Where(e => e.Name.Contains("Network"))
                     .Take(10)
                     .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public HomeController(CompanyService companyService)
{
    this.companyService = companyService;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Company> companies = this.companyService.getCompanyList();

    return View(companies);
}
```

**View:**

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var company in Model)
    {
        <li>@company.Id | @company.Name</li>

        if (company.Contacts.Count > 0)
        {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var contact in company.Contacts)
            {
                <li>@contact.FirstName</li>
            }
        </ul>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

In other hand, judging from your implementation, I feel like you may need to work more on fundamental skills like data structure, C#/OOP fundamental then ASP.NET MVC in respective order.